# Angular 2 Form help...backend functionality

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am trying to write backend functions for a form I made in an angular 2 project. I am very new to angular, I did the front end part fine but struggling to do the backend. I want to fill the fields and when you hit the submit button, have the data be sent as a json object to the console

Link to the form https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mppcdu

Comment: what do you get for `this.onboardForm.value()` ?

Comment: You really aren't taking advantage of `angular`'s out of the box forms features in the provided code. I'd suggest reading https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms and try starting over with a `FormGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this

in your example.ts file

```
    newSampleForm: FormGroup;

           ngOnInit(){
              this.newSampleForm = new FormGroup({
                'userName':new FormControl(null),
                'password':new FormControl(null)
              })
             }


            onSubmit() {  
              let body = this.newSampleForm.value; 
              console.log(body);
           }

    or you can declare JSON object and assign form values to it.

    submitData :{
    'userName':string,
    'password':string
    }

    onSubmit() {
    this.submitData = {
    'userName':this.newSampleForm.get('userName').value,
    'password':this.newSampleForm.get('password').value
    }
    }
```